# How to shutdown Visual Studio process started by EnvDTE

Tags: visual-studio, envdte

I have written a console app that uses EnvDTE to process 10 or so solutions and refactor them programmatically - changing references and project structure

```
        var envDteType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");

        var envDte = Activator.CreateInstance(envDteType, true);
        var dte2 = (DTE2)envDte;

        var solution = (Solution4)dte2.Solution;
        solution.Open(filename);

        // execute various tasks

        solution.Close();
        // how to dispose of dte2?
```

The trick is, when my app finishes there are Visual Studio processes still running presumably opened by EnvDTE. I shutdown my only Visual Studio instance visibly running and they persist.

Is there a way to shutdown those processes that the EnvDTE object spawned?

The following seems to have no effect

```
dte2.Application.ActiveWindow.Close();
```

Comment: `dte2.Quit();`  It doesn't quit until all objects are finalized, ensure your console mode app quits as well or use GC.Collect() to hurry it along.  If you debug your app and don't let it end normally then you have to use Task Manager to shoot the zombies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans' is correct - `dte2.Quit();` does the job